# PostgreSQL: Using the .pgpass file

Tags: postgresql, authentication, connections

I have been reading up on the `.pgpass` file, but I can’t get it working for me.

My `.pgpass` file looks something like this:

```
127.0.0.1:5432:accounts:fred:p@55w0rd
```

I set the privilege to `0600` (this is on CentOS Linux) and try:

```sh
psql
```

Where I get the message:

> psql: error: FATAL:  database "…" does not exist

where `…` is my user name.

I can successfully connect if I use:

```sh
psql -u … -d accounts
```

so I don’t think my `.pgpass` file is doing its job.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.pgpass` does not define a default database. It only provides the *passwords* for a combination of hostname, database and username.

But it's still up to you to provide the hostname, database and username when you start `psql`.

When you just run `psql` without any arguments you are not providing a username or password - and it's not taken from `.pgpass` - there could be hundreds of entries in there. Which one should `psql`take?

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING) `psql` then assumes your current operating system user as the default user. If no database is provided `psql` assumes a database with the name of the user (so with the name of the current operating system user if you also don't provide a username).

You apparently want to connect to a database that has a different name than the username you want to use. Hence you have to provide a database name. If `fred` is your operating system user, then `psql -d accounts` should be enough.

If you want to use a user and database other than the defaults, use the [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) `PGUSER` and `PGDATABASE`.

Comment: I understand. That makes sense, as then the `.pgpass` would also allow alternative connections. Thanks.

Comment: The original post had `pgass` instead of `pgpass` lol