# set the pgpass, still ask me password

Tags: postgresql

system: Ubuntu 20.
related post: [PostgreSQL: Using the .pgpass file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/297741/postgresql-using-the-pgpass-file)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables/117470#117470
overall means I permanent set the following enviroment variable in **/etc/profile**

```
export PGPASSFILE='/home/jian/.pgpass'
export PSQLRC='/home/jian/.psqlrc'
export PGUSER=admin
export PGDATABASE=test
export PGPORT=5433
```

I also did **sudo chmod 600 /home/jian/.pgpass**

```
 sudo cat /home/jian/.pgpass
```

return

```
localhost:5433:test:admin:password
localhost:5432:test:admin:password
```

when I type psql, it still promopt me to password. I thought all things are properly set.
later I deleted the second password line, still ask me password.

Comment: Did you confirm, that the environment variables are really set for your current user (e.g. `echo $PGUSER`)? What happens if you type: `psql -U admin -d test -port 5433 -h localhost`. Btw: why set PGPASSFILE or PSQLRC for **all** users to the same value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So I need set the enviroment variable and set the ubuntu current user. both should be same? can I make it first check the enviroment variable value?

Comment: Why the sudo in `sudo cat /home/jian/.pgpass`.  It seems suspicious.  Why do you need to become root to read your own pgpass?

Comment: @jjanes because I follow this tutorial https://tableplus.com/blog/2019/09/how-to-use-pgpass-in-postgresql.html to chmod 600 the file.

Comment: @jjanes file permission something like: `-rw------- 1 admin admin 28 Jul  6 10:34 /home/jian/.pgpass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be the owner of the password file. Supposing that your user name is `jian`, you'd have to change the ownership:

```bash
sudo chown jian /home/jian/.pgpass
```